# Facebook Login on PhoneGap, nothing happens

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

I am trying to run the sample app included in the [PhoneGap Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) in Android.

**PROBLEM**

Upon clicking on "Login", a dialog asks for my permission ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AQ68.png)), but after clicking OK it goes back to the main screen and nothing happens.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I've installed the Facebook APK in my phone, and the Facebook SDK for Android in Eclipse, and linked the SDK to the sample app. I also generated my key hash, using the keystore I use to export the app, and added it to the app's config on Facebook.

I added the `com.facebook.LoginActivity` to the manifest like this:

```
<manifest>
...
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="TestaFB" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

And added the plugin like this, in `res/xml/config.xml`:

```
<cordova>
  <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
  </plugins>
</cordova>
```

I modified the `index.html` to use the version of cordova I'm using (2.6.0) and put my `appId` in the JS:

```
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: '361413583977115',
          nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
          useCachedDialogs: false
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);
      authUser();
      updateAuthElements();
  });
```

I have no idea what I did wrong.

However, I found out that if I grant permission to the app using my computer, and then try to use the app, it works.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @nathvarun No, I quit the job.